# How to view all windows services (including those disabled or not running) in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, service

I am working on a security project (for educational purposes) for which I have compiled a list of services which SHOULD be on a computer. It then subdivides them into which ones should be disabled, manual, or automatic. Obviously, it's quite tedious to run services.msc and peruse the list manually, so I'd like to give it a shot in python. Unfortunately, I can't find a way to list all of the services on a computer using Python. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Tim Golden's [WMI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WMI/) module.  Something like:

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI()
for service in c.Win32_Service():
    print(service.DisplayName)
```

Comment: I should have specified, I'm running Python 3.4. I don't believe WMI is compatible. Or at least, no Python install is showing up when I try to install.

Comment: I'm not sure either...There is this blog entry from 4 years ago which leads me to believe it *might* be though: http://ramblings.timgolden.me.uk/2009/10/16/getting-wmi-to-work-with-python-3x/

Comment: Ah, I stand corrected. The exe didn't work, but downloading the zip worked fine. Thanks!